# Cannot connect to database after restart using oracle.jdbc.{OracleConnection}

Tags: oracle, scala, jdbc

I'm currently working on a Scala project. This program can run normally, but when this program is executed during a database restart,  it throws an error which basically means that it cannot connect to the database (if I'm right).

I already pin-pointed the problem by debugging it and the problem seems to happen when it's executing this line:

```scala
rs = psmt.executeQuery()  // error happens here
```

Here is the entire code: **EDITED**

```scala
def SomeNameOfDef2(sql: String, paramList: List[String]): immutable.HashMap[String, String] = {
    CallConn   //Open Connection

    var ret = immutable.HashMap[String, String]()
    val psmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)
    var rs: ResultSet = null
    var ErrorChecker : String = "" //NEW FLAG HERE
    try {
      var i = 0
      for (p <- paramList ){
        i += 1
        psmt.setString(i, p)
      }
//NEW WHILE LOOP METHOD IN FINALLY CLAUSE, IF ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED AT FIRST TRY   
if (psmt != null && !psmt.isClosed()){
        try {
          ErrorChecker = "FALSE"

          rs = psmt.executeQuery()

        }catch {
            case e: Throwable =>

            ErrorChecker = "TRUE"
        }finally {
          while (ErrorChecker == "TRUE"){
            try {
              ErrorChecker = "FALSE"
              CallConn
              rs = psmt.executeQuery()
            }catch {
              case e: Throwable =>

              ErrorChecker = "TRUE"
            }finally {
              if (ErrorChecker == "TRUE"){
                //DO NOTHIING CONTINUE WHILE LOOP
              }else {
                ErrorChecker = "FALSE"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      if (rs != null && !rs.isClosed() && rs.next)
        for (col <- 1 to rs.getMetaData.getColumnCount )
          ret += rs.getMetaData.getColumnLabel(col).toLowerCase -> rs.getString( col )
    } finally{
      try {
        rs.close()
      } catch {
      case e: Throwable =>
        log.error(e,"Error encountered here1")
      }
      try {
        psmt.close()
      } catch {
        case e: Throwable =>
          log.error(e,"Error encountered here2")
      }
    }
    ret
  }
```

The error thrown is:

```
[05-08-2021,14:32:20.500] - RECONNECTION_ATTEMPT_INTERVAL is missing, defaulting to 1000ms
[05-08-2021,14:32:21.515] - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28547: connection to server failed, probable Oracle Net admin error

[05-08-2021,14:32:21.515] - RECONNECTION_ATTEMPT_INTERVAL is missing, defaulting to 1000ms
[05-08-2021,14:32:22.531] - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28547: connection to server failed, probable Oracle Net admin error

[05-08-2021,14:32:22.531] - RECONNECTION_ATTEMPT_INTERVAL is missing, defaulting to 1000ms
[05-08-2021,14:32:23.562] - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28547: connection to server failed, probable Oracle Net admin error

[05-08-2021,14:32:23.562] - RECONNECTION_ATTEMPT_INTERVAL is missing, defaulting to 1000ms
[05-08-2021,14:32:24.593] - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28547: connection to server failed, probable Oracle Net admin error

[05-08-2021,14:32:24.593] - RECONNECTION_ATTEMPT_INTERVAL is missing, defaulting to 1000ms
[05-08-2021,14:32:25.625] - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28547: connection to server failed, probable Oracle Net admin error

[05-08-2021,14:32:25.625] - RECONNECTION_ATTEMPT_INTERVAL is missing, defaulting to 1000ms
[05-08-2021,14:32:26.656] - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28547: connection to server failed, probable Oracle Net admin error

[05-08-2021,14:32:26.656] - RECONNECTION_ATTEMPT_INTERVAL is missing, defaulting to 1000ms
[05-08-2021,14:32:27.687] - java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

[05-08-2021,14:32:27.687] - RECONNECTION_ATTEMPT_INTERVAL is missing, defaulting to 1000ms
[05-08-2021,14:32:28.718] - java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

[05-08-2021,14:32:28.718] - RECONNECTION_ATTEMPT_INTERVAL is missing, defaulting to 1000ms
[05-08-2021,14:33:09.140] - Message dequeued [c8d01f19d8bf2c07e053fa2f1fac9c5c] ...
[05-08-2021,14:33:09.156] - @13100164501 has been queued for processing. (1 Queued Processes)
[05-08-2021,14:33:09.156] - Message dequeued [c8d01f1a5a052c05e053fa2f1fac1d87] ...
[05-08-2021,14:33:09.172] - @13100164500 has been queued for processing. (2 Queued Processes)
[05-08-2021,14:33:09.453] - @13100164501 Process moved for processing (1/10). 1 remaining queued processes.
[05-08-2021,14:33:09.453] - Processing message from queue ...
[05-08-2021,14:33:09.515] - All Processes have been executed.
[05-08-2021,14:33:09.593] - QListener - @13100164501 payload received with requestType[900]. . .
    [05-08-2021,14:33:09.593] - DataUnit - Error encountered here1
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ftsp.xx.reactive.common.BaseDataUnit.SomeNameOfDef2(BaseDataUnit.scala:273)
        at com.ftsp.xx.reactive.common.DataUnit.loadProcLog(DataUnit.scala:261)
        at com.ftsp.xx.reactive.common.DataUnit$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(DataUnit.scala:275)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
        at com.ftsp.xx.reactive.common.BaseDataUnit.aroundReceive(BaseDataUnit.scala:16)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:590)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:559)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
    [05-08-2021,14:33:09.593] - OneForOneStrategy - ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
    Process ID: 26460
    Session ID: 1967 Serial number: 23895
    
    java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
    Process ID: 26460
    Session ID: 1967 Serial number: 23895
    
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:777)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:673)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T2CPreparedStatement.java:546)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
        at com.ftsp.xx.reactive.common.BaseDataUnit.SomeNameOfDef2(BaseDataUnit.scala:264)
        at com.ftsp.xx.reactive.common.DataUnit.loadProcLog(DataUnit.scala:261)
        at com.ftsp.xx.reactive.common.DataUnit$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(DataUnit.scala:275)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
        at com.ftsp.xx.reactive.common.BaseDataUnit.aroundReceive(BaseDataUnit.scala:16)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:590)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:559)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Basically, I just wanted my program to run normally after a database restart.

Comment: Well, the connection it had to the database is dead. You have to handle the error by catching it and attempting to create a new connection - or just restart your program when your restart your database (that's something that shouldn't happen too frequently).

Comment: Do you use connection pooling? Usually any connection pooling library should handle this for you.

Comment: @ibre5041: I think we are using connection pooling since we have imported a local library like this:
import com.ftsp.util.db.OracleDbPool

Comment: @RealSkeptic: I'm trying a solution like creating a while loop which try to call the CallConn to open a connection then try executing the executeQuery( ). but in any case, you know a better method kindly point me, please :)